# Face Tracking object's position in depth stream of Kinect V2

Tags: c#, windows, kinect, kinect-sdk, windows-rt

I have used Green screen effect in my code & now need position of the eye, Mouth & Nose which will be able to track & use i think via Camera or Color Stream so because of that not able to get proper position inside the green screen detected body which will be display as per the depth stream. so my question is how to apply proper position of an face object's in depth stream because of which the green screen effect(Back-Ground Removal) appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of FacePointsInColorSpace, use FacePointsInInfraredSpace.

The color space has a resolution of 1920x1080, while the infrared space has a resolution of 512x424 pixels.

Green screen implementation is most probably using the depth space to extract the proper pixels.